# InterlockedCompareExchange in windows 98 environment

Tags: winapi, interlocked, windows-98

I am forced to run some applications in `windows 98 se`. `vc6` has strange `InterlockedCompareExchange` definition:

```
void* InterlockedCompareExchange(void**, void*, void*);
```

`msdn` defines it like this however (since `windows xp`):

```
LONG InterlockedCompareExchange(LONG*, LONG, LONG);
```

Does anyone remembers how to use it (I need to atomically get value of interlocked variable)?

Comment: IIRC, it doesn't matter: Win98 didn't have threads anyway.

Comment: @MSalters: Sure it did.

Comment: @MSalters `win98` has threads and it has other `Interlocked*` functions as well.

Comment: Well, they've been designed to be API-compatible with Windows NT, which had multi-CPU support since 3.1 or so. Doesn't mean Win9x actually supported a second CPU or dual-core CPU, it did have the API functions but still executed one thread at a time.

Comment: @MSalters yes it's all about simulation in manner of fast switching between threads but it doesn't make operations atomic. i still need to atomically check my variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 98 did not support 64bit, so `void*` and `LONG` are the same byte size.  Most OSes actually use the `LONG` definition, but if VC6 is using `void* then simply type-cast where needed:

```
LONG value;
LONG ret = (LONG) InterlockedCompareExchange((void**)&value, (void*)ExchangeValue, (void*)CompareValue);
```